# Target multiple divs containing toggles to change the styles on click individually

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web app I have several rows containing data with toggles at the end of each row. On `click` of each toggle, it should change the `opacity` of the entire row and contents.

I've made a simplified version of this on codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYeeyp

The issue I am facing is writing the JS to target the states of the divs individually. Currently when I click on a toggle in one row, it changes the styles for all the others. I did try using a seperate id for each row but it would be too messy in my function if I have multiple rows. Is there a way I can change my function to make sure that only the row where the toggle is being turned on and off, changes its state?

My current JS code:

```
 $('.toggle').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.item-row').addClass('disabled-view');
  } else {
    $('.item-row').removeClass('disabled-view');
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are adding class to all the `.item-row`. Instead just target the `.item-row` closest to clicked `.toggle` and for that use `.closest()`.

```
$('.toggle').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.item-row').addClass('disabled-view');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.item-row').removeClass('disabled-view');
    }
});
```

See the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRXgpZ) here.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Was not aware of that property

Answer (score 0):

what about calling the parent to do the trick ;)

```
$('.toggle').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('disabled-view');
} else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('disabled-view');
} });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! However with this would it work even if I have nested my toggle in several divs and wish to target the whole row/wrapper?